# How to convert a grouped pandas dataframe into a numpy 3d array and apply right-padding?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sequence, numpy-ndarray

In order to feed data into a LSTM network to predict remaining-useful-life (RUL) I need to create a 3D numpy array (No of machines, No of sequences, No of variables).

I already tried to combine solutions from stackoverflow and managed to create a prototype (which you can see below).

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                   'V1': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2],
                   'V2': [4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1],
                  })

df_desired_result = np.array([[[1, 4], [2, 2], [-99, -99]],
                       [[2, 3], [-99, -99], [-99, -99]],
                       [[3, 2], [3, 1], [4, 5]]])

max_len = df['ID'].value_counts().max()

def pad_df(df, cols, max_seq, group_col= 'ID'):
    array_for_pad = np.array(list(df[cols].groupby(df[group_col]).apply(pd.DataFrame.as_matrix)))
    padded_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(array_for_pad,
                                                                 padding='post',
                                                                 maxlen=max_seq,
                                                                 value=-99
                                                                )
    return padded_array

#testing prototype
pad_df(df, ['V1', 'V2'], max_len)
```

But when I apply the code above to my data, it applies the right-padding correctly but all values are set to 0.0.
I can't fully figure out this behaviour, I noticed that in the first line of my function, I get returned an array with nested arrays for 'array_for_pad'.
Here is a screenshot of the result:
[result padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw06z.png)